# sql using select in sub queries with joins

Tags: sql, select, join

I am trying to answer question # 8 on the SQLZoo.net website.  Here is the link.  It should be pretty simple, but I think that I am just over thinking myself.  Here is the link:

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

subquery isn't really needed but a simple self join. By joining the table with itself using `LEFT JOIN`, you can get your desired result but during the joining of tables, you need to filter those years on chemistry subject on the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.yr
FROM    nobel a
        LEFT JOIN nobel b
            ON a.yr = b.yr AND b.subject = 'Chemistry'
WHERE   b.yr IS NULL AND
        a.subject = 'Physics'
```

[Click Here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F53ND.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct yr 
from nobel 
where subject='Physics' 
    and yr not in ( select yr from nobel where subject='Chemistry')
```